# Scala Reflection giving different outputs for class attribute type

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have this piece of code that extracts class attribute types

```
object Main extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val fields = typeOf[User].members.filter(!_.isMethod).map { sig =>
    println(sig.info)
  }
}
```

When i run it in Intellij the output is

```
String
Int
```

But when i run in Scala the output is

```
String
scala.Int
```

What is going on here?